# How to mount a remote directory using sshfs when the server keeps forwarding me?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mount, sshfs

maybe this question was asked before but here I go:
I want to mount the user directory of my account on the server of the university I go to. Usually when I log in through ssh I just type in:

> ssh user@computer-room-ip

Now I want to mount my directory to my home computer (Ubuntu), but as it turns out, just using "user@computer-room-ip" doesn't work. When I connect via ssh it automatically forwards me to a local computer and only then it logs me in. This is the reason why my console says:

> sudo sshfs user@computer-room-ip:~/Documents mountpoint/
>
> user@computer-room-ip:~/Documents: No such file or directory

So is there still a way to mount the directory or am I doomed to use scp everytime I want to continue working on my project from elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote directory (parameter that comes after colon **:**) is already specifies remote home directory (of user), so no tilde **~** is needed, just use directly *path/relative/to/home*.

$ sshfs user@computer-room-ip:Documents mountpoint

(You shouldn't need **sudo** either..)